# How to access sms's or call logs on devices with cordova apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been searching for answers to the above question but not able to get a solid reply to this.

Android can access call logs, I guess, what about sms's?

Thanks

Comment: You can't access either on iOS

Comment: @Paulw11 can native iOS app access these..?

Comment: No, regardless of how the app is written, this information is not available without a jailbreak.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was wondering how Truecaller does it, on Android it shows who is calling and on iphone the number is detected by the app and then it shows who called

Comment: A lot of it is explained in their FAQ - https://truecaller.desk.com/customer/en/portal/topics/902078-iphone/articles  It doesn't provide live identification of callers.  You have to send the number from your missed calls to their app and then they search for details. They also add numbers that they identify as "spam" callers to a contact that they add to your address book, so that the iPhone shows this contact detail indicating "spam" when one of those numbers calls