# How to access call log or call event on android and iphone while building cordova apps

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, calllog

I had posted a similar question

[How to access sms's or call logs on devices with cordova apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344040/how-to-access-smss-or-call-logs-on-devices-with-cordova-apps)

and based on that we have no permission to access call logs.

How does Truecaller access call logs or call events - on Android it shows who is calling and on iphone the number is detected by the app after call and then it shows who called.

Can we do the same for Cordova apps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get call log history using Cordova CallLog plugin for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809391/how-get-call-log-history-using-cordova-calllog-plugin-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

I did find a [cordova-calllog-plugin](https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin) to access device call history. Hope this should help, not tried personally though.

Also looking at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277250/phonegap-api-to-query-call-logs), i guess its definitely possible to acheive this in corodva apps